# I want to calulate percentage using angular 2/4.

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to calculate a percentage using a previous value with present value using angular 2/4. Suppose i have a input type 'number' value= 10. If I am adding a value below 50(value=20) it has to 25%, the value more than 50 it has to 50%. Can any one help me out from the scenario I want in angular 2/4

Comment: Put (change) handler on input and save value as this.prevValue at the and of handler. So next time changd event occurs yiu havr prevValue for calculations

Comment: can you please add me a code here.it would be helpful

Comment: myOnChangeEvent(event) {
let currentValue = event.target.value;
this.percentageValue = currentValue / this.prevValue;
  // Do something
this.prevValue = event.target.value;
}

Comment: And add some check for this.prevValue === undefined  fot the fist handler run

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [angular pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes).

1. Create a `*.pipe.ts` file:

   ```
   import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

   @Pipe({name: 'countPercentage'})
   export class countPercentage implements PipeTransform {
     transform(value: number, previous: number): number {
       return yourCalculateMethod(value, previous);
     }
   }
   ```
2. Use the pipe in your html file:

   ```
   <p>{{value | countPercentage: previous}}</p>
   ```

---

Or, you can use the input DOM event, for example, an `onChange` event.

1. In HTML file:

   ```
   <input (onchange)="myOnChangeEvent($event)"/>
   ```
2. In TS of JS class:

   ```
   previousValue: number;
   myOnChangeEvent(event) {
     if(!previousValue) return '';
     let percentage = previousValue * 1.0 / event.target.value / 100;
     this.previousValue = event.target.value;
     return percentage>50? '50%' : percentage + '%';
   }
   ```

If this is what you mean.

Comment: can you please add  onChange event code using switchcase it has to accept all percentage 250

Comment: @NarendraVarma  why when previous=10 and present=20, the persentage=25%? How do you count the persentage?